# How to assign a material to all strokes of a layer?

Tags: python, materials, shaders, grease-pencil

I'm trying to assign a material to all strokes in a particular gpencil layer.

I add the grease pencil object as:

```
gpencil= bpy.ops.object.gpencil_add(view_align=False, location=(0, 0, 0), type='EMPTY')
```

Then I add a new layer as:

```
gp_layer= gpencil.data.layers.new('lines', set_active=True)
```

And finally the stroke as:

```
gp_stroke = gp_frame.strokes.new()
gp_stroke.display_mode = '3DSPACE'
gp_stroke.points.add(count=2)
gp_stroke.points[0].co = p0
gp_stroke.points[1].co = p1
```

How can I set the material index for `gp_stoke`?

Comment: Hi. The link to the gist wasn't valid so I removed it from the post... If you still have it, please add it back to the question. Thanks